# Mod_wsgi Apache Bottle.py: Cannot import python module "server"

Tags: python, apache, server, mod-wsgi, bottle

I am trying to use Bottle.py and mod_wsgi together but I am getting a strange error that I cannot fix.
When I try to make a curl request ("curl http://localhost/myapi/hello1") I get the error: "ImportError: No module named server". However, if I take out the "import server" line in my app.wsgi file and try "curl http://localhost/myapi/hello2" it works just fine. I have tried adding to the WSGIPythonPath, WSGIDaemonProcess, etc. and nothing has worked. Does anyone see anything I may be doing wrong?

**Note:** The "/usr/local/www/wsgi-script" path is successfully being added to sys.path, so that isn't the issue. I also do have a **init**.py file in the "/usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts" directory and the permissions are all 777.

```
[root@my_vm httpd]# ls -lt /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/
total 8
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  95 Mar 21 14:42 server.py
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 318 Mar 21 14:37 app.wsgi
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   0 Mar 20 19:53 __init__.py
```

**Using Versions:**

Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)

Python 2.7.5

Bottle 0.12.9

## /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/server.py

```
import bottle
from bottle import route

@route('/hello1')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

## /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/app.wsgi

```
import os
import sys
import bottle
from bottle import route

server_loc = "/usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts"
if not server_loc in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, server_loc)

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))

print(sys.path)

@route('/hello2')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!\n"

import server
application = bottle.default_app()
```

## /etc/httpd/conf.d/myapi.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    WSGIScriptAlias /myapi /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/app.wsgi

    <Directory /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

## EDIT:  Adding python traceback

## /etc/httpd/logs/error_log

```
[Thu Mar 22 13:39:18.234573 2018] [core:notice] [pid 18172] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Thu Mar 22 13:39:29.628352 2018] [:error] [pid 18174] ['/usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts', '/usr/lib64/python27.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
[Thu Mar 22 13:39:29.628514 2018] [:error] [pid 18174] [client ::1:35838] mod_wsgi (pid=18174): Target WSGI script '/usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/app.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Mar 22 13:39:29.628525 2018] [:error] [pid 18174] [client ::1:35838] mod_wsgi (pid=18174): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/app.wsgi'.
[Thu Mar 22 13:39:29.628539 2018] [:error] [pid 18174] [client ::1:35838] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Mar 22 13:39:29.628556 2018] [:error] [pid 18174] [client ::1:35838]   File "/usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/app.wsgi", line 18, in <module>
[Thu Mar 22 13:39:29.628625 2018] [:error] [pid 18174] [client ::1:35838]     import server
[Thu Mar 22 13:39:29.628645 2018] [:error] [pid 18174] [client ::1:35838] ImportError: No module named server
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual Python traceback and error?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Sure i'll update the post now

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I just updated the post! I also tried deleting the __init__.py and same error.

However, if I moved the server.py into another directory inside the directory (aka /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/server.py --> /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/inner_dir/server.py), and do "import inner_dir.server" instead of "import server", it starts working. Do you know why that may be?

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong. Since you should use mod_wsgi daemon mode anyway, maybe configure Apache to use that. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/configuration-guidelines.html#defining-process-groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the solution that I found worked for me:

When I moved the server.py into another directory inside the directory (aka /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/server.py --> /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/inner_dir/server.py), and do "import inner_dir.server" instead of "import server", it started working.